# Calling Java8 method with BiFunction parameter fro Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, interop

I have this piece of Groovy code that makes use of Java8 CompletableFutures:

```
       CompletableFuture<Integer> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({
            Thread.sleep(1500)
            return 1
        })

        CompletableFuture<Integer> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            return 2
        })

        def closure = { Integer a, Integer b -> a + b }
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result = future1.thenCombineAsync(future2, closure)
        println(result.get())
```

Problem is that I can't get the call to thenCombineAsync in the 2nd last line to work. Whatever I do, the second argument, which is required to be a BiFunction, is not accepted by the compiler as types don't match. I've tried a lot of things. Any solution that gets this accomplished greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Groovy?  Do you have `CompileStatic` turned on?  I just pasted your script into the groovyconsole, and it works and prints 3

Comment: Seems to work with `@CompileStatic` as well... can you come up with an example that fails?  Or what version of Groovy you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention. Am using Groovy 2.4.6 with @CompileStatic. IntelliJ flags the call to thenCombineAsync red, because of type mismatch. Expected behavior is 3 to be printed to the console but nothing is printed there.

Comment: Your example code works for me in the 2.4.6 groovy console with `@CompileStatic`...

Comment: When you ignore that IntelliJ flags the 2n last line red, you still don't get 3 printed to the console. Unhappily, nothing is printed to the console. You can try it out to see :-)

Comment: Sorry, it prints 3 to the console. I was talking rubbish there. But IntelliJ keeps flagging that line as red. maybe just a problem of IntelliJ?

Comment: Okay, it works if I do it like this: def closure = { Integer a, Integer b -> a + b } as BiFunction. Then IntelliJ is happy. But is there a better way?

Comment: Tried `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> closure = { Integer a, Integer b -> a + b }`